# HttpClient always send Unauthorized for calling anonymous method

Tags: asp.net

`clinet.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:5088/AuthValidator",Email)`
I am trying call another service using httpClient, but always have the same status code:Unauthorized. Attributes of method which should invoked.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> Validate([FromBody] string Email)
```

I really want to know how I should Invoke this method

Comment: Post the code and any exceptions or compilation errors as text in the question itself. Images can't be copied, compiled, tested or googled

Comment: Based on ASP.NET routing convention, the correct URL to POST should be `http://localhost:5088/AuthValidator/Validate` if this `Validate` method belongs to `AuthValidatorController`.